# In Experience editor "remove component" button got disabled

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore 8.1, When we open Experience editor, the "Remove Component" and "Move Component" buttons got disabled.
How can we make them enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When that happens, if it's not security-related, it's usually because the component you're trying to remove or the placeholder that the component is in is not marked as editable.

Ensure that the component and the placeholder are editable.

Comment: Yes, all components and placeholders are editable. In fact it was working few days ago.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks Craig.